# isearch-forward, call-interactively, and isearch-filter-predicate

Tags: isearch, filtering, call-interactively, isearch-filter-predicate

Here are two use cases where I call `isearch-forward` with some filter predicate.

```el
(let ((isearch-filter-predicate (lambda (a b) nil)))
  (funcall 'isearch-forward))

(let ((isearch-filter-predicate (lambda (a b) nil)))
  (call-interactively 'isearch-forward))
```

Why is it that only the first one works?  Is there a way to have the `call-interactively` call take `isearch-filter-predicate` into account?

It seems I need `call-interactively` if I want commands that leave isearch (e.g., `C-n`) to be executed properly (that is, `C-s C-n` should go to the next line).

Comment: Why do you say that you need to use `call-interactively` for keys such as `C-n` to quit Isearch? What are you trying to do - are you trying to define a command? If so, add an `interactive` spec. If not, use `isearch-mode`.

Comment: `C-n` does quit isearch, but does not go to the next line when called using `funcall`.  My ultimate goal is to have a command that `read-key-sequence`s and executes the associated function with a *specific* `isearch-filter-predicate`.

Comment: @Drew One advantage of using `call-interactively` is that the original interactive spec is used for the called command. One only needs `(interactive)` for the caller. Injection of `(interactive-form 'old-command)` makes debugging with `edebug` a pain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in the doc string of `isearch-forward`:

> If this function is called non-interactively with a nil *NO-RECURSIVE-EDIT*,
>   it does not return to the calling function until the search is done.
>   See the function `isearch-mode` for more information.

In your first form

```el
(let ((isearch-filter-predicate (lambda (a b) nil)))
  (funcall 'isearch-forward))
```

you use a nil value for the optional argument `no-recursive-edit` of `isearch-forward`. In that case the incremental search runs in a `recursive-edit` call **within `isearch-forward`** and the control flow does not leave the local scope of your `let`-form while `isearch-mode` is active.

In the second form

```el
(let ((isearch-filter-predicate (lambda (a b) nil)))
  (call-interactively 'isearch-forward))
```

you start the isearch with the interactive call of `isearch-forward`. The command `isearch-forward` just starts `isearch-mode` and exits. The control flow is **not within the `isearch-forward` function form** while the incremental search is running.

An alternative way to call `isearch-forward` with user-defined `isearch-filter-predicate` that uses `call-interactively` is given in [the answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51650/2370) to the question about [searching for bold text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51622/2370).