# How can I search for bolded text?

Tags: search, text-properties, isearch

My reasons for doing so are exactly like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271550/how-can-i-search-for-bolded-or-underlined-text , but the accepted solution there is to use vim. I don't fancy that, especially when we can use `man` directly in emacs.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the interesting isearch-matches by the function registered at the variable `isearch-filter-predicate`.

I demonstrate this below in a simplified way.

1. I only check the first letter of the match. I accept the match if that letter is bold.
2. [Apparently `face-attribute` interferes with isearch](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51651/2370) in Emacs 26.2. For that reason I introduced the variable `isearch-face-bold-p-fun` and set it to the more general predicate function `isearch-face-p` which just checks whether there is any face at the beginning of the match. Searching man-pages with that default works quite well.

```el
(defun isearch-face-p (start end)
  "Return faces at START, preferring those named in buffer text there."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (face-at-point nil t)))

(defun isearch-face-bold-p (start end)
  "Return a bold face at START."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (cl-some (lambda (face) (and (facep face) (face-bold-p face nil t))) (face-at-point nil t))))

(defvar isearch-face-bold-p-fun #'isearch-face-p
  "Isearch filter for bold text.
The value should be a function suitable for `isearch-filter-predicate'.")

(defun isearch-bold-forward-end-fun ()
  "Uninstall isearch filter `isearch-face-bold-p-fun'."
  (remove-function (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (remove-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun))

(defun isearch-bold-forward ()
  "Like `isearch-forward' only accepting bold matches."
  (interactive)
  (add-function :after-while (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun)
  (call-interactively #'isearch-forward))
```

Tested with `emacs -Q` Emacs version `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12`.

EDIT: Adapt Drew's proposal to use `INHERIT` arg t for `face-bold-p`.

Comment: See my answer at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51651/2370, for why your `isearch-face-bold-p` fails on a `man` page.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer: Using @Tobias's `isearch-face-bold-p`, but corrected per [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51661/105) to this:

```el
(defun isearch-face-bold-p (start end)
  "Return non-nil if face at START is bold."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (cl-some (lambda (face) (and face (face-bold-p face nil t))) (face-at-point nil t))))
```

You can do what you want using just **`C-z & isearch-face-bold-p`** while searching.  That is, you can add predicate `isearch-face-bold-p` on the fly. All you need is the filter predicate.  You can also save the resulting behavior, by using **`C-z n`** followed by the search-command name you want, e.g. **`isearch-bold-forward`**.

IOW, you can get the same behavior, including defining the search command, just by doing **`C-z isearch-face-bold-p C-z n isearch-bold-forward`**.  (From then on you can just use that new command.)

For this on-the-fly Isearch filtering you need [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). See [Dynamic Isearch Filtering](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering).

Comment: Hi Drew. Ha ha ha. That `THING` arg of `face-at-point` is really funny! Generate a `*test*` buffer with `C-x b`, put the word `bold` in, place point in front of `b` and debug `M-:` `(face-at-point 'THING)`. I have already replaced `(face-at-point t t)` with `(face-at-point nil t)` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `INHERIT` for `face-bold-p`!

Comment: @Tobias: I thought that's what you wanted: to preferentially pick up a face name from the buffer text. But since you don't, I've changed my answer to use the same thing, nil.