# Why is face-attribute interfering with isearch?

Tags: faces, isearch

Question: Why does `face-attribute` interfer with isearch filter predicates?

The following code is part of [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51650/2370) to [the question about searching for bold text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51622/2370).

If I set the variable `isearch-face-bold-p-fun` to the predicate function `isearch-face-p` searching the Emacs man page for `daemon` with `isearch-bold-forward` works like expected. Isearch stops at bold occurences of the word `daemon`.

If I set `isearch-face-bold-p-fun` to `isearch-face-bold-p` instead and search the Emacs man page for `daemon` no matches are found.
(There are even stranger effects in other constructed examples.)

The main difference between `isearch-face-p` and `isearch-face-bold-p` is the call of `face-bold-p` which works with `face-attribute`. That motivates my question.

```el
(defun isearch-face-p (start end)
  "Return non-nil if face at start-position is bold."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (face-at-point t t)))

(defun isearch-face-bold-p (start end)
  "Return non-nil if face at start-position is bold."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (cl-some (lambda (face) (and (facep face) (face-bold-p face))) (face-at-point t t))))

(defvar isearch-face-bold-p-fun #'isearch-face-bold-p
  "Isearch filter for bold text.
The value should be a function suitable for `isearch-filter-predicate'.")

(defun isearch-bold-forward-end-fun ()
  "Uninstall isearch filter `isearch-face-bold-p'."
  (remove-function (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (remove-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun))


(defun isearch-bold-forward ()
  "Like `isearch-forward' only accepting bold matches."
  (interactive)
  (add-function :after-while (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun)
  (call-interactively #'isearch-forward))
```

Tested with emacs -Q Emacs version GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12.

---

EDIT:

Drew solved why the search in the man buffer for Emacs failed.
Pityngly that is not the only case that fails.
In the following code I adapt Drew's proposal to add the non-nil `INHERIT` argument to `face-bold-p`.

```el
(defun isearch-face-p (start end)
  "Return non-nil if face at start-position is bold."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (face-at-point nil t)))

(defun isearch-face-bold-p (start end)
  "Return non-nil if face at start-position is bold."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (cl-some (lambda (face) (and (facep face) (face-bold-p face nil t))))))

(defcustom isearch-face-bold-p-fun #'isearch-face-bold-p
  "Isearch filter for bold text.
The value should be a function suitable for `isearch-filter-predicate'."
  :group 'isearch
  :type 'function)

(defun isearch-bold-forward-end-fun ()
  "Uninstall isearch filter `isearch-face-bold-p'."
  (remove-function (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (remove-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun))

(defun isearch-bold-forward ()
  "Like `isearch-forward' only accepting bold matches."
  (interactive)
  (add-function :after-while (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) isearch-face-bold-p-fun)
  (add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook #'isearch-bold-forward-end-fun)
  (call-interactively #'isearch-forward))
```

New Test:
Isearch for `bold` with `M-x` `isearch-bold-forward` starting at the beginning of the following org snippet.

Point jumps from the `b` of the first occurrence of `bold` to the `o` of the **second** (non-bold) occurrence.

```
Some of the text here is **bold**.
Some intermediate text.
We do not need to bold everything.
Here is some more **bold** text.

Local Variables:
mode: org
End:
```

Answer (score 2):

The bold text you see in your test does not use face `bold`. It uses face `Man-overstrike`. And `(face-bold-p 'Man-overstrike)` returns nil.

`(face-bold-p 'Man-overstrike)` evals this: `(face-attribute 'Man-overstrike :weight frame inherit)`, which returns `unspecified`.  Then `(memq 'unspecified '(semi-bold bold extra-bold ultra-bold))` returns `nil`.

You need to pass a non-nil value for arg `INHERIT` to `face-bold-p`:

`(face-bold-p 'Man-overstrike nil t)` returns this: `(bold extra-bold ultra-bold)` (which is non-nil - the predicate is satisfied).

Comment: Thanks Drew, that was definitive one part of the problem. But, there is pityingly more. See my EDIT in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about abstracting it that way:

```
     (defun ar-next-fontset-attribut-atpt (attribut &optional frame inherit)
  "Takes the desired attribut.

Think of ‘bold’, ‘slant’, ‘underlined’ etc.--"
  (while (and (not (eobp))
          (progn (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n\f")
             (not (ignore-errors (eq attribut (ignore-errors (face-attribute (face-at-point) :weight frame inherit))))))
          (goto-char (or (next-property-change (point))
                 (point-max)))))
  (push-mark)
  (unless (eobp) (goto-char (next-property-change (point)))))
```

If needed, replace "bold" by "slant" or whatever attribut searched for:

```
(defun ar-next-bold-atpt ()
  (interactive)
  (ar-next-fontset-attribut-atpt 'bold))
```

A test:

```
(ert-deftest ar-next-bold-atpt-test()
  (with-temp-buffer
    ;; (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
    (insert "Some of the text here is **bold**.
Some intermediate text.
We do not need to bold everything.
Here is some more **bold** text.

Local Variables:
mode: org
End:")
    (org-mode)
    (font-lock-ensure)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (ar-next-bold-atpt)
    (should (eq (char-after) ?.))
    (should (eq (char-before) ?*))
    (ar-next-bold-atpt)
    (should (eq (char-after) ?\s))
    (should (eq (char-before) ?*))))
```